# AWS Lambda custom node image

Tags: node.js, go, aws-lambda, dockerfile, debian

I am creating a custom image for AWS lambda following the steps given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-image.html#nodejs-image-clients)

The dockerfile uses bookworm (21) base image

```
#Function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM node:20-bookworm as build-image

# Global arg
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    make \
    cmake \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev


# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}


# Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install

# AWS runtime interface client
RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric

# Stage 2 multistage
FROM node:20-bookworm-slim


# Set NPM cache lambda fs is read-only
ENV NPM_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/.npm

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Set entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/npx", "aws-lambda-ric"]

# Pass function handler to the runtime
CMD ["index.handler"]
```

The lambda works fine but the image fails jfrog scanning due to vulnerability on golang packages .

```
Critical | sha256__a1f707ed6d2119246 | github.com/golang/go | 1.20.5   | [1.20.9]      | Go   | CVE-2023-39323 
:
```

The CVEs are in these packages -
**github.com/golang/go (1.20.5 - suggested version 1.20.9 onwards) and golang.org/x/net (0.15.0 - suggested version 0.17.0)**

I tried updating the go version (not sure if that is the correct approach) by adding the following to Dockerfile out

```
# Install Go 1.20.11 
RUN wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.20.11.darwin-amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.20.11.darwin-amd64.tar.gz && \
    rm go1.20.11.darwin-amd64.tar.gz

# Set Go environment variables
ENV GOPATH="/go"
ENV PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"
```

But the CVE still shows up. Any pointers as to how to fix the vulnerability.

Comment: have you tried to compile your go code on another go docker image and copy the compiled go executable on the node image, therefore you remove the need for the go environment on the node image?

Comment: I do not have any go code, a simple nodejs hello world lambda that I want to test. I am assuming it is from the debian image or the additional tools installed. Downloading Go and setting the path was to see if I can upgrade go in the image to eliminate the vulnerability.